# Rails formtastic is asking for a country plug-in.. I don't want it. Anyone know how to tell it I don't want it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic, country

I'm using formtastic and I've got a field country.. I'm getting this error when I attempt to display the screen.

> To use the :country input, please install a country_select plugin,
>   like this one: https://github.com/jamesds/country-select

Now.  I don't want to use any plugin.. It's free text, and I want to keep it that way.

Anyone know how to remove this requirement?   Should be easy as... but I'm buggered if I can see how.

```
= semantic_form_for @store, {:html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }} do |f|
  = f.input :default_country
```

Comment: Can you show the exact form field you've got in your view template? I'm not sure without the actual code, but my guess is that you're stumbling into a convention that Formtastic assumes you're following by virtue of the name of your input, but that you could change slightly to avoid this problem. For example, if you're using the helper `country_select` then this would trigger the need for the plugin, where it sounds like what you want is whatever the plain text field helper is for Formtastic so that a user can type in the name of a country from their keyboard rather than selecting from a list.

Comment: I just added the code... and yes I do totally want the user to enter the country in free text.  I at least want to be given the option :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add 
, :as => :string

to the end of the line that's causing the error

```
= semantic_form_for @store, {:html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }} do |f|
  = f.input :default_country, :as => :string
```

Answer (score 3):

**In Rails 4, formtastic with country select input field:**

Add 'country-select' to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'country-select'
```

If I use semantic form select, it doesn't shows previously saved value. So, the following is **not working** properly:

```
=f.input :country, as: :select, collection: country_options_for_select
```

So have to use standard form elements to get **working**:

```
=f.select :country, collection: country_options_for_select
```

Comment: it might be due to an update or something, but the following does work for me if you pass in the previously saved value =f.input :country, as: :select, collection: country_options_for_select(@user.country)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this plugin works out of the box (note the underscore instead of the dash):

https://github.com/chrislerum/country_select